# opening a chromeclient in the same activity

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I was wondering if it was possible to open a chrome client in the same activity using `webview` instead of opening chrome? It will be so helpful to me as I am working on `webrtc` and it doesnt work with `webclient`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This](https://github.com/googlearchive/chromium-webview-samples/tree/master/webrtc-example) should be the solution for your problem. Best regards